# How can I parse date time correctly in (Year month Date H:M:S p(am or pm))?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a date and time field, `Date hour and minute` in the following text format, in my Google Analytics data source:

> 2022/06/27 12:36:00 AM

I want to convert it to this:

> 27 June 2022 12:36:00 AM

The whole issue is with the standard of date, firstly I have firstly format the time from 24 hour to 12 hour format, than combine the date and time.
After that it is appearing in a text form, I am now trying to Parse using [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) function with this formula:

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p)', Date hour and minute)
```

However, it returns NULL values:

[image: attempt]

### Sample data:

Data set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amUlyWb25azhvJ7w7wmAZfy2Q_adD4QrF2AKpG5DUSc/edit?usp=sharing)):

| Date hour and minute |
| --- |
| 2022/06/26 08:36:00 PM |
| 2022/06/27 11:35:00 AM |
| 2022/06/27 12:54:00 AM |
| 2022/06/27 11:38:00 AM |
| 2022/06/27 12:36:00 AM |
| 2022/06/27 03:30:00 PM |
| 2022/06/28 01:15:00 PM |
| 2022/06/28 09:48:00 AM |
| 2022/06/28 01:16:00 PM |

Expected output:

| Date hour and minute |
| --- |
| 26 June 2022 08:36:00 PM |
| 27 June 2022 11:35:00 AM |
| 27 June 2022 12:54:00 AM |
| 27 June 2022 11:38:00 AM |
| 27 June 2022 12:36:00 AM |
| 27 June 2022 03:30:00 PM |
| 28 June 2022 01:15:00 PM |
| 28 June 2022 09:48:00 AM |
| 28 June 2022 01:16:00 PM |

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0a670847-dcb3-4b7c-98ba-7cc765d1b485) report

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using the below. #1 transforms the text field to a Google Data Studio recognised date & time field, while #2 uses that [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) to display the date & time fields in the exact format required (the example date formats in the question will be used to explain)

### 1) Text > Date & Time

The attempted [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) in the question had an extra `)` (when removed it works as expected):

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p", Date hour and minute)
```

The below summarises the role of each symbol (more information and additional symbols in the [Format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements) page):

```
2022/06/27 12:36:00 AM
↑↑↑↑/↑↑/↑↑ ↑↑:↑↑:↑↑ ↑↑
  %Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p
```

### 2) Specific Format

Wrap the above with [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334):

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p", PARSE_DATETIME("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p", Date hour and minute))
```

This function also used the symbols from [Format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements) page:

```
27 June 2022 12:36:00 AM
↑↑ ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑:↑↑:↑↑ ↑↑
%d  %B   %Y  %I:%M:%S %p
```

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/47060b19-7352-42eb-bd35-4c97879bcdcd) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pe1pSi_4m3c6sovpHthWEps_z4PO846td8wTnx0SPLE/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]